# allow certbot validation and github action connection to digitalocean network firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I have this digitalocean droplet that I served as staging instance and has network firewall on it. As it is a staging instance I made it work like a private access only by adding our outline vpn ip on http and https port, everything is working except when validating website with certbot and github action not able to connect to the droplet instance. How do I whitelist the github and certbot? Any help, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu? Whichm

Comment: How is the access restricted? Is it from within the server, using iptables, nftables or whatever, or from some Digital Ocean config panel?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** In order to better diagnose your issue, please edit your question with the current version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Comment: @waltinator yes

Comment: @muru it block by the digitalocean network firewall because if I disable the digitalocean platform, its all working

Comment: Then this a question you should ask to Digital Ocean support. Their firewall is not Ubuntu, and it's offtopic here